# Remove last character from the first word in a string

Tags: regex, vba, excel

*I'm using RegEx to search for the string*

```
If RegExp.test(Cel.Value) Then
    Debug.Print Left$(Cel.Value, Len(Cel.Value) - 1)
End If
```

---

*This is my Data*

```
3250A WEST SEM
110055K KEALY RD
804B WEST AMERICA
804 EAST AMERICA
```

---

*Result should be*

```
3250 WEST SEM
110055 KEALY RD
804 WEST AMERICA
804 EAST AMERICA
```

What is the best way to delete the last character?

Comment: regexp.replace with a better pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^(\d+)[a-zA-Z]*(\s+.*)$
```

And replace by this:

```
$1$2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/9)

Comment: Upvoted for providing the first working regexp solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
(\d+)(\w{1})(\s.+)
```

- `(\d+)` - capture one or more digits
- `(\w{1})` - capture one letter that you want to remove - if you have examples 123XX SOMEWHERE then to capture XX you would use `(\w+)` or `(\w{1,2})` if you think there will be 1, or 2 characters following the number.
- `(\s.+)` - capture a space followed by anything

When you want to replace you just want to remove the second match group (`(\w{1})`) and join the first and third - hence the `$1$3` in the `Replace` function below:

```
strReplaced = objRegex.Replace(CStr(varTest), "$1$3")
```

Example VBA code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim varTests As Variant
    Dim varTest As Variant
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strReplaced As String

    varTests = Array("3250A WEST SEM", "110055K KEALY RD", "804B WEST AMERICA")
    strPattern = "(\d+)(\w{1})(\s.+)"

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    objRegex.Pattern = strPattern

    For Each varTest In varTests
        strReplaced = objRegex.Replace(CStr(varTest), "$1$3")
        MsgBox strReplaced
    Next varTest

End Sub
```

Fancy diagram of regex:

[image]

Comment: Elegant! I just don't do enough Regex to know it this well.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx scenario - If you can find *<some numbers><single letter><single space>* at the **beginning** of the string, then change the pattern to *<single letter><single space>* and replace it with a single space.

```
Option Explicit

Sub stripAlphaSuffix()
    Dim i As Long, regex As Object

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            With regex
                .Global = False
                .MultiLine = False
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = "^[0-9A-Z ]{3,8}"
            End With
            If regex.Test(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) Then
                regex.Pattern = "[A-Z ]{2}"
                .Cells(i, "A") = regex.Replace(.Cells(i, "A").Value2, Chr(32))
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

just to throw in a not-RegEx solution:

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim word As String

For Each cel In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    word = Split(cel, " ")(0)
    cel.Value = Replace(cel.Value, word, Left(word, Len(word) - 1))
Next
```

Comment: Extra info is always great - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As `VAL` strips non numerics off a alphanumeric string starting with a number then you could try this (which doesn't presume that there is always a character to be replaced)

> `VAL("3250A")` = `3250`

Would be more elegant if it didn't need to append the rest of the string :)

```
Dim StrIn As String
Dim X
StrIn = "3250A WEST SEM"
X = Split(StrIn, Chr(32))
MsgBox Val(StrIn) & Right$(StrIn, Len(StrIn) - Len(X(0)))
```